# React App, remove debug code from production build

Tags: javascript, debugging, npm, build

I'm creating a React App in npm environment.

In my JS code I have something like this in many JS files:

```
...
let url = loc.protocol + "//" + loc.hostname + (loc.port ? ":" + loc.port : "") + "/" + baseUrl;
if (DEBUG) {
  url = "http://myTestPlatform.com/webapp";
}
...
```

When I run my WebApp in my dev environment (using npm start) I want the debug code to be enabled but when I'm creating the production build (using npm build) I would like to remove all debugging code.

How can I do that?
Thanks,

Sebastien

Answer (score -1):

In your app.js (or main server file), you can set up your logging middleware before creating any routes, which will only be used if you're not in production. This will be the only time you need to do this.

```
'use strict'

const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const morgan = require('morgan') // or your logging middleware

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
  // Logging middleware (non-production only)
  app.use(morgan('dev'));
}  

...

module.exports = app;
```

Comment: My question was probably not clear. 

What I want is the code 
if (DEBUG) { url = "http://myTestPlatform.com/webapp"; }

to be completely removed from the production build.